# NEED Help in Hosting a WCF service on Web Hosting IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, hosting

I'm trying to Host a WCF service on the web Hosting IIS. But failed to do so. I've a test Service Project which I'm currently trying to Host just for checking purpose. The project runs and host successfully within the Visual Studio 2010 Development environment.

I would really appreciate if You could guide me to the process of Hosting a WCF service. I tried couple of things like create a new directory from the Control Panel's File Manager and Upload the files there, But could be successful. Apparently, The hosting only accepts the "Index" File type to be run like (index.html) when I try to put the service project on the httpdocs folder.T

I googled A lot but the only best thing I could find was hosting locally on IIS. That didn't work as well for me. I'm a newbie to this so Your help would really be appreciated. Thank you.

My hosting domain is "www.collect-info.com‏".

Answer (score 0):

This returns quite a few results: [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20host%20WCF%20service%20in%20iis&oq=how%20to%20host%20WCF%20service%20in%20iis&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j0l3j69i62l2.8357j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

It would really help to tell us what you have tried and what error messages you are getting.  This site is intended to help with specific technical questions you have - it is not meant to guide you through the entire process of hosting a web service.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, My aim was just to get the guide line But since I'm quite newbie at this stuff, I wrote it just to get the answer of my level. 
Though I've gone through these results and followed some. But my problem is not related to making or consuming wcf service. It's purely related to hosting it to IIS web Hosting. Currently, I see my web Host only displays result which are index.html type. Can't open Service.svc files on the browser. Gives forbidden 403 error. Help ?

Comment: It sounds like you have not registered your service model correctly in IIS.  Have a look for 403 and ServiceModelReg.exe -i.